# Sync Project with Gradle Files button disappeared from Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, gradle, synchronization

Importing an Android project into Android Studio, the error "Design editor is unavailable until next gradle sync" appears:

[image]

You can see that there is no option: Sync Project with Gradle Files:
[image]

Going to: File -> Settings -> Main Toolbar -> Android.MainToolBarActionGroup -> Sync Projects with Gradle Files

But the Apply option is "off" in the sense of being "locked", so there's no way to change anything:
[image]

And all options for Clean Project are not available:

[image]

Please what to do to fix this?

Comment: did u tried invalidate caches / restart option ??

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Yes, I tried this.

Answer (score 1):

It can be found at the top of Android Studio, or at the top left side.  [image: top of screen on left] Look for the little elephants.

Comment: Thank you very much, Kristy Welsh.
But there is no elephant icon: https://uploaddeimagens.com.br/imagens/BrfQCf0

Please, someone knows how to come back to the normal graphic interface of the Android Studio?

Comment: Even for me, there's no icon or this setting available in File.

Answer (score 0):

This problem was caused because I opened the project in Android Studio. But the right to do is to **IMPORT** the project.
Thank you very much.